# How to access and print variable that is used inside another function and evaluate to True

Tags: python, server, boolean

I have open source web server written in Python. Inside the server I have a **wrong_checker()** function which takes a value and checks it against **real_value**. I can access this function.

```py
def wrong_checker(value_of_check):
    return (value_of_check == "" or (not value_of_check and real_value)) \
           or value_of_check != real_value
```

Now I want to write function **find_value()** to find and print the value of **real_value**.

```py
def find_value():
        ???????
```

Comment: Design your program such that these functions are methods of the same object and so can share state through the instance (better), or communicate though module globals (worse), or otherwise use one of the mechanisms designed into the language. Don't try to come up with some hack using metaprogramming or obscure language features when there are well-supported and clear-to-the-reader alternatives.

Comment: It is a little unclear, but I'd guess you have a design flaw here (especially if "real value" is some sort of password). That being said, you should look into the "Singleton" pattern. Create a "service" that is a singleton and stores the real_value as read only.

Comment: Did you mean: `def find_value(): return real_value`?

Comment: Did you mean: `def find_value(): return wrong_checker(0)`?

Answer (score -1):

Well, normally you should write a comparer funciton

```
def compare(value_a, value_b):
    #compare stuff and return 1, 0 or -1
    #1 for value_a greater, 0 for equal and -1 for value_b greater
```

Then you are more flexible.

Comment: By my reading, the question title indicates that the part the OP is having trouble with is accessing the variable across function boundaries, as opposed to being able to implement logic to run the comparison once a means to access the value is established. What part of the question leads you to believe that implementing a comparator function would solve the OP's problem?

Comment: (That said, per the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), questions where it's unclear what the OP wants should be closed rather than answered, until/unless edited for clarity).

Comment: I thought about architectural problems in this code example I have seen and suggested a solution.

Comment: The "architectural problem" being asked about is not knowing how to share a value across function calls. This doesn't solve it: The values can just be compared with `==`, there's no point to a custom comparator.